# How to allow child to remain on last drag place inside Draggable Widget?

Tags: flutter, draggable

There is widget named as **Draggble** in **Flutter**. I added one Text widget inside it as child and then want allow user to drag inside it's parent widget. But everytime, I finish drag, *child(Text) shows on old position*.

I have seen in the document if there is any flag to update to allow dragged position for child, but it seems like not having it.

```
child: Draggable<int>(
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Text(
        "Drag me to center",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 26
      ),
   ),
   feedback: Text(
     "Wow! it's dragging",
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 26),
   )),
```

Is there anyway through which dragged child remains on the latest drag position?

Comment: Have you tried DragTarget. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DragTarget-class.html

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu If possible, can you please share any example of the same. Actually I am struggling to understand the relation between Draggable and DragTarget and how to implement it.